# It seems like GDI+ TextureBrush Bug

Tags: gdi+

before mention, I Cant Speak Enginlish That very well

Recently I make Windows Desktop Application(On Windows7) using GDI+

I think Gdiplus::TextureBrush has a bug. I hope anyone found this bug like me.

that bug is like below

step1.
there is a image that has 500dpi, 6250 * 7819 size

step2
Loading the image by using `Gdiplus::Image::FromStream()`
the image name is `"image1"`

step3.
Creating Graphics graphics(HDC);

step3.
Creating `Gdiplus::TextureBrush brush = Gdiplus::TextureBrush(image1);`

step4
`graphics.FillPath(brush);`
currently everything is ok, you can see the right image on screen

step5
creating another Graphics from a bitmap
`Graphics::Bitmap* bitmap = new Graphics::Bitmap(size.CX, size.CY), PixelFormat32bppARG);`
`Graphics* anotherGraphics = Gdiplus::Graphics::FromImage(bitmap);`

step6 (Here Bug Occur)
`anotherGraphics.DrawImage(image1);`
and then detach the new image from `anotherGraphics`.
but new image is weird, new image like filled entirely by one pixel from the origin image

but next time, it never happens again..
only one time during the app life time

what is wrong....

Comment: It could be some weird type of monochrome. It could also be undefined behavior. I would simplify the graphics until it is working, then build up and check often that it is still working - that's what I do when I hit a wall.

Comment: On a side note - it is very unlikely to be a bug in any case.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap::FromStream` method  has second `arg` that is `useEmbededColorManagement` (not sure that is correct name anyway) I did put the True in it and then its working well. The arg looks like not related this bug.

I still don't know why its working but I solved this problem.